# TCL script to extract the elements from a file in a directory and make a list

Tags: tcl

I am having one problem as stated below

Problem Description

I am having some "sv" extension files , I am using "glob" to extract the matching files , Now in these matching files , I need to split them and extract the elements and create different lists.

For example

```
set files [glob -type f modified_rtl_files/*/*{wrapper_hsm}*]
```

This command gives me these two files :

```
modified_rtl_files/mbist_wrapper/mbist_wpper_hsm_pkram.sv modified_rtl_files/mbi_wrapper/mbist_wrapper_hsm_sysram.sv
```

Now I am extracting the filename with the below command

```
foreach element $files {
set c [split [ file tail [ file rootname $element ] ] "_" ]
echo $c
}
```

This is giving me

```
pkram
sysram
```

But I need to set them to two independent list

```
$mem1 
$mem2
```

```
$mem1 should be pkram 
$mem2 should be sysram
```

Whenever I am trying to create something like this , both the elements are getting printed

```
foreach element $files {                                                                                              
set c [split [ file tail [ file rootname $element ] ] "_" ]                                                                      
set d [ lindex $c 3]                                                                                                             
set mem1 [ lindex  $d 0 ]                                                                                                        
puts $mem1                                                                                                                       
}
```

It is printing both

```
pkram 
sysram
```

I want independent variables .

Comment: I am not sure , what is not clear in this question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the values you want into an array instead of numbered variables:

```
set files {modified_rtl_files/mbist_wrapper/mbist_wpper_hsm_pkram.sv modified_rtl_files/mbi_wrapper/mbist_wrapper_hsm_sysram.sv}
set mem {}

foreach f $files {
    lappend mem [file rootname [lindex [split $f _] end]]
}

puts [lindex $mem 0]  ;# => pkram
puts [lindex $mem 1]  ;# => sysram
```

Or use the [`lmap`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm) command to make it more concise:

```
set mem [lmap f $files {file rootname [lindex [split $f _] end]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I am trying it out and come back to you with some clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do generated names with `set`:

```
foreach element [lsort $files] {
    set mem[incr i] [lindex [split [file tail [file rootname $element]] "_"] 3]
    puts [set mem$i];  # <<< How to *READ* a variable with a generated name
}
```

(Always sort the output of `glob` if you care about the order at all; it's not guaranteed to come in any order at all or with any consistency).

***BUT DON'T DO THIS!***

Generated variable names are a pain to work with precisely because they can't be used with the `$` language syntax. You're much better using (associative) arrays because those *do* work with that:

```
foreach element [lsort $files] {
    set mem([incr i]) [lindex [split [file tail [file rootname $element]] "_"] 3]
    puts $mem($i)
}
```

The values will not be in `mem1` and `mem2`, but rather `mem(1)` and `mem(2)`.